# Связь 2-ух скриптов Python

Tags: python

Всем привет, у меня возникла проблема. Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы 2 скрипта пайтон были связаны друг с другом работая одновременно.
Пример:
В 1 скрипте я в input() вписываю значение, а во втором оно выводится на экран. Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Для этого надо смотреть в сторону процессорного взаимодействия (pipe, multiprocessing, etc)

Answer (score 0):

```py
def first():
    n = input()
    return n


def second(value):
    print(value)

second(first())
```

Comment: Возможно я не слишком корректно описал свою проблему, необходимо сделать так, что при запусук 2-ух разных файлов .py они могли "общаться" друг с другом